# TFS undo to last shelve

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, shelve

What I want to do: I made some changes in code and I want to make some kind of "checkpoint" (like git commit), then continue working and being able to simply undo changes to last "checkpoint". I don't want to use Check In.

If I'm not mistaken, it could be done by Shelving, but I'm unfortunately not sure how exactly I can achieve that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Pending Changes" tool window in Visual Studio just select "Shelve" at the top, enter a name and click the "Shelve" button:

[image]

To go back to your "Checkpoint", restore your Shelveset via Actions => Find Shelveset => Rightclick => Unshelve

Comment: but the Unshelve would restore everything to the checkpoint, right? what if I made 10 changes, Shelved, then made another 10 changes in the same files which were shelved and i wanted to undo only 1 file from the 10, to the "checkpoint"(last shelve). Your solution would undo all changes to the checkpoint

Comment: @asdfok Only if undo your changes, otherwise they will be merged. However it sounds like you rather need an extension like "Local History": https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AronDCurzon.LocalHistoryforVisualStudio

Comment: So, TFS in default, can´t do this as GIT : do changes, commit, continue working, making changes, undoing some changes, and then pushing (check-in) everything together.. Well, thanks for the suggestion for Local History, I will look into it

Comment: No, TFS works different from Git in that regard. Another option would be to branch the folder you're working in, commit changes to that branch and when you're done merge your branch back to the original folder.

Answer (score 1):

Shelving is similar to stash in git. To replicate that kind of workflow would involve either checking out to a previous changeset and/or rolling back changesets. I've created multiple shelvesets before (V1, V2, etc), but it is less than ideal.